# Will a B-tree with preemptive splitting always have the same height for any input order of keys?

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

Will an even degree B-tree that uses preemptive splitting always be the same height for a given set of keys, regardless of insertion order? Without preemptive splitting, I know that this is false, different insertion orders will produce different heights, but with preemptive splitting I feel like it always produces the same height no matter the input order.

Comment: I was preparing a long-winded answer to your question, but one thing that I don't understand is why you would think that preemptive splitting would make a difference?

Comment: Preemptive splitting will always prevent a full node from existing within the tree which I believe is sometimes necessary to get trees of different height without preemptive splitting.

Comment: Can you be precise about what the rules of the B-tree and insertion would be? There are many variants. Is the degree the minimum or maximum number of children. Do leaf nodes have the same maximum number of keys as internal nodes, and is that limit set to the degree minus 1? Or can leaf nodes have more keys than that? All this has to be defined very precisely to avoid that an answer will miss the mark.

Comment: Degree is max number of children, leaf nodes can have same number of keys of internal, which is degree-1.

Answer (score 0):

> Will an even degree B-tree that uses preemptive splitting always be the same height for a given set of keys, regardless of insertion order?

No, it will not. It will suffice to consider a counter example.

Take for instance a (maximum) degree of 4, such that the number of keys in any node is between 1 and 3. Then consider the insertion of the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

#### 1. In the order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

After insertion of the first three values, we get a full root node:

[image]

The insertion of 4 will split the root node, after which the new value is added in the right child:

[image]

5 will be added to that same child without problem, and when 6 is added, that child splits, moving its middle key (4) to the root:

[image]

Similarly 7 will be added, and when 8 is added, the rightmost child splits, moving its middle key (6) to the root:

[image]

Now when 9 is added, the root is pre-emptively split, moving 4 upward to become the new root:

[image]

And so we are at 3 levels.

#### 2. In the order 5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4

We repeat the process from scratch in this modified order. After having added the first seven values, we get this tree:

[image]

The next value will move a key up to the root, and the final value can be added without any problem:

[image]

This completes the illustration of the counter example: the same set of keys can lead to a 2-level or a 3-level tree, depending on the insertion order.

Comment: Could you give some feedback to this answer? Does it answer your question?